# Excel - Convert accounting formats to number

Tags: vba, excel

I am always having issues with corrupted formats in Excel (too many Excel sheets from too many users).  Every once and a while, Excel likes to randomly convert cells into accounting format (and Euro, at that...).  I'm trying to write a simple VBA script to convert these annoying accounting formats back to number format.

I've tried a few variations of the below, but I'm getting an Application error... any thoughts?

```
Sub Test2()
Dim sht As Worksheet
  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Application.findFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_([$€-2] * #,##0.00_);_([$€-2] * (#,##0.00);_([$€-2] * ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    sht.Cells.NumberFormat = "0.00"
  Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Why bother trying to find a specific format ? just select all cells and set to what you want...

Comment: See the comment to Gerardo's answer.  In short, because they're spread all over a large workbook, that has various formats that I don't want to change.  No easy way to select a range and change at once

Comment: I'd bet your formats are not changing randomly...

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you in addition to answer your question.

From experience, files that are shared across many users have an absurd amount of cell styles. Removing them goes a long way:

```
Sub StyleKill()
Dim sty As Style
On Error Resume Next
For Each sty In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
     If Not sty.BuiltIn Then
         sty.Delete
     End If
Next styT
End Sub
```

Regarding format matching and reformat, seems odd that you want to change only certain cells, why not applying a format for an entire range?

Comment: Thanks for the StyleKill macro, I'll give that a go.    The issue is my workbook is about 15 sheets, with a bunch of different formats (dates, numbers, percentages etc).   It's really only the accounting formats I want to kill, but they're spread all over, not just in one range.  So not really an easy way for me to select a range and change them, without affecting others cells I don't want to change

Comment: I suspected that.Take a look at this post https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153594

Comment: Thanks for that, just tried it.  I'm still getting an Application Error with this line though:   Application.findFormat.NumberFormat = "_([$€-2] * #,##0.00_);_([$€-2] * (#,##0.00);_([$€-2] * ""-""??_);_(@_)"

Comment: sadly vba is not very insightful when it comes to errors. However I did find a good reference for you https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/help-vba-currency-numberformat-error-excel/ca55e147-fce9-4182-80d6-c6e3b2a80d26